# Which study design is best for the following?

Tags: case-control-study

I have a data set in which all patients have a particular disease. The disease has three varieties labeled as 0, 1, and 2 in the data set. I want to know the association of a particular drug with this disease. Some of the patients are taking the drug some are not.

For the case-control study, If I assume the patients with disease as the outcome variable, then we don't have any control because all patients have the outcome (All of them have the disease). If I assume the patients on the drug as the outcome variable and the disease as the exposure variable, then we can't have any unexposed in the 4x4 table. So a case-control study is not possible.

What study design to use for it?

I shall be highly thankful for your guidance.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated, Muhammad. The types of analysis that are appropriate and helpful depend on both the data and the analytical objectives. Can you say more clearly what you want to statistically estimate or the inferences that you might make? (The first step in data analysis should be to visualise the data with some graphs.)

Answer (score 0):

if you dont have data for patients who dont have the disease then you cant model the effect of drug on disease.